# mouseover.js load grayscale image

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, grayscale

I have a problem with a mouseover script. Everything works as it should but I have a small issue that I don't know how to solve. More precisely, the mouseover script creates a grayscale image hover effect. When the page loads the colored images are showing for a short time (1 second or less) and then the javascript is applied and they are all grayed out which is exactly how things should work.

How can I make it so that the colored images will not appear before the javascript is applied? Basically, I want the grayscale images to appear when the page loads not after. Is it possible?

You can see the script [here](http://pastebin.com/yeBtedcg) and the webpage in question [here](http://www.capital-restaurants.com/web/menu).

Comment: You shouldn't link out. Include your source and examples.

Comment: You have conflicting goals: waiting until the images are loaded so you can process them and wanting to have them processed before they've been loaded.

Comment: @MihaiStancu what should they do in instances with very large amounts of source code?

Comment: @le_garry I'm sorry i don't understand what you mean? What should they do now that they have a conflict in a huge pile of code?

Comment: I guess it can be reduced, the amount of code they show, but I am asking what is proper etiquette for posting large amounts of code?

Comment: There is a FAQ regarding proper etiquette on Stack Overflow. It states that you should reduce the problem you have to the simplest reproducible form in order to reduce code and emphasize the problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the images from the HTML and load them dynamically.

I would use `<a class="placeholder" href=""></a>` as placeholders for the `<img src="" />` and would style the links to either be hidden or go well with the design.

```
$('a.placeholder').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    var image = new Image(); // this is not yet visible in the DOM.
    image.onload = grayscale; // change the grayscale function to accept
                              // event parameters
    image.src = src; // this triggers the onload event which
                                     // grayscales the image
    var dom_image = $('<img />').attr('src', src);
    $(this).replaceWith(dom_image);
});
```

Of course you have to be doing the above on document ready not on window load.